# MSBbuild wants to copy C:\pagefile.sys. any idea why?

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am using cruisecontrol.net +msbuild. It has been working well for sometime and for the last two days I am getting this error.  why is it trying to copy pagefile.sys? here is the errorlog. Thank you all in advance for your help.

Error message:
"[CDATA[Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to 
C:\CCNet\PublishedFiles\_PublishedWebsites\merp\roslyn\pagefile.sys". 
Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'C:\pagefile.sys' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: So this morning I git Cloned a repo, modified identity server project, and deleted a couple lines like
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.1\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props and then tried to compile using VS 2015, and got

 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4105,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys". The process cannot access the file 'C:\pagefile.sys' because it is being used by another process.

Can't repro now, crazy!

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523580/strange-build-error-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2015-wants-to-copy-pagefile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange Build error after upgrading to Visual studio 2015 wants to copy pagefile.sys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523580/strange-build-error-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2015-wants-to-copy-pagefile)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some .target files have been accidentally edited in the .NET Framework directories, as it is said [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0405d810-0ace-4ecf-ae1e-7721d449e036/the-target-copyoutofdatesourceitemstooutputdirectoryalways-does-not-exist-in-the-project?forum=Vsexpressinstall). A sort of workaround I would prefer before reinstalling VS, would be changing the swap file disk in System Settings (if you have other logical/physical drives).

Comment: <target name="_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" "[CDATA[Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to C:\CCNet\PublishedFiles\_PublishedWebsites\merp\roslyn\pagefile.sys". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'C:\pagefile.sys' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here is the scenario. I am using cruisecontrol.net and msbuild is a task. i am not using vs to build at all. OS is win 2008 R2