# Error MSB3027: Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am consistently getting this error with VS 2013:

> Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys".
>   Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. Unable to copy file
>   "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys". The process cannot
>   access the file

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure C:\pagefile.sys exists or not in use.

Comment: Pretty bizarre error, copying the paging file is never possible.  It never makes sense to try, Roslyn certainly does not do this.  Fix your project.

Comment: Finally found the answer from this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32784349/5470285

Comment: I had similar problem with VS 2019 16.8.4, I had 2 work around.
--> Downgraded to VS 2019 16.7.7 
--> Moved VS solution and project to the first level folder to reduce the path length.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As indicated in [this answer from Pramod's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32784349/1872500) the problem stems from the **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** nuget package, specifically upgrading from version **1.0.0** to  **1.0.1**.

For me however, downgrading using Visual Studio caused further build errors. To solve the problem I had to manually edit my csproj and packages.config files, removing all references to **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** and **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**.

Specifically, this meant:

- Removing the relevant `<Import Project="...` sections for all versions of both libraries (usually towards the beginning of the csproj)
- Removing the `<Reference Include="...` sections for both versions of both libraries
- Removing the `<Error Condition="!Exists(...` sections for both versions of both libraries from within the `EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports` target section
- Removing all `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` packages from the packages.config.

I was then able to manage the projects nuget packages in VS and (in order) :

- Add **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** version **1.2.2**
- Add **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** version **1.0.1**

This solved the pagefile build error, and the runtime error which prompted me to try and upgrade in the first place.

Comment: Following this is the only thing that worked for me.  Also, instead of getting 1.2.2 of Microsoft.Net.Compilers I got 1.3.2 and things worked fine as well.

Comment: Also happens upgrading from version 1.3.2 to 2.4.0 probably because some library get into the cache.

Answer (score 10):

I removed these packages from nuget package manager since I do not use them:

- **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**
- **Microsoft.Net.Compilers**

Now everything works.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a different solution to this error.
In my case I had been moving around a project within my solution (I put it in a subfolder). My references to packages (located in `%solutionfolder%/packages`) in the project file were broken and I fixed them manually.

However, there are two supplement imports that I forgot:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

I first updated the first one from `..\packages` to `..\..\packages` (lazy as I am). Building the project after that gave me the pagefile.sys error.

Updating the second import (same change: `..\packages` to `..\..\packages`) solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Clean Solution/Rebuild Solution steps resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines from .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I delete this line in .csproj file

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
```

And worked to me.

I use Visual Studio 2019, and I don't know why apears suddenly this error in my project.

Answer (score 0):

This error went away for me when I quit the process of running my app in Windows PowerShell then restarted it.

Answer (score -1):

Not much to go off of, but I would suggest recording your issue using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe)

Once you have `procmon` running, you want to record (or trace, in other words) your issue with `VS2013`. Once you're done recording, you'll want to filter the results by process (in your case, `devenv.exe`), so press `Ctrl-T` to open the Process Tree, and find `devenv.exe`.

Select it, and then click the "Include Subtree" button. Close the Process Tree window, and select `Tools -> Count Occurrences` from the top menu. Set the Column dropdown box to 'Result' and press the Count button. The output will be a collection of results along with their respective counts. You can usually get a good idea of what's going on by looking at these results. For example, if you see a lot of results involving `ACCESS DENIED` or `FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS`, then most likely your issue is related to permissions.