# Team city cannot copy pagefile.sys because it is being used by another process

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, build-error

I am trying to get TeamCity up and running for a CI / CD server.  So far I have it connected to my Git repo, it pulls the repo and builds.  Great.

Now I am trying to publish it.  (My web server is also the CI server and agent).

I keep getting this error:

C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f56e1490ff15a5c4\P4P.Web\P4P.Web.csproj(1373, 5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "\pagefile.sys" to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\P4P\build\pagefile.sys". Beginning retry 8 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file '\pagefile.sys' because it is being used by another process.

It ultimately fails and fails the entire publish process.

C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f56e1490ff15a5c4\P4P.Web\P4P.Web.csproj(1373, 5): error MSB3027: Could not copy "\pagefile.sys" to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\P4P\build\pagefile.sys". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f56e1490ff15a5c4\P4P.Web\P4P.Web.csproj(1373, 5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "\pagefile.sys" to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\P4P\build\pagefile.sys". The process cannot access the file '\pagefile.sys' because it is being used by another process.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428409/error-msb3027-could-not-copy-c-pagefile-sys-to-bin-roslyn-pagefile-sys-ex) ow SO.  I tried downgrading the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform and Microsoft.Net.Compilers packages to 1.0.0.  I have even tried removing them entirely.

I have looked at all csproj files for references to these packages (including the package.config).  Nothing.

I have no idea where to even begin to fix this.

My server is running Windows Server 2012 R2.  I installed VS professional.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you say you're "trying to publish it"? Where is your output coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

The problem starts when you upgrade the DotNetCompilerPlatform to version **1.0.1.**

To work around this issue you can downgrade to version **1.0.0** using the NuGet package manager.

EDIT: If you uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform AND Microsoft.Net.Compilers, and then install the DotNetCompilerPlatform (has a dependency on the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package so it will automatically install that) package again the error disappears for good so it seems.

Also check this issue link - [error MSB3027: Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428409/error-msb3027-could-not-copy-c-pagefile-sys-to-bin-roslyn-pagefile-sys-ex)