# error MSB3027: Could not copy "/src/libwkhtmltox.dll" to "/app/build/libwkhtmltox.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dinktopdf

I am using DinkToPdf to generate pdf document in .net core , it is obligatory to add [these files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwlvA.png) to  the project , when I run `dotnet build . -c Release -o /app/build` in jenkins i get this Error `error MSB3027: Could not copy "/src/libwkhtmltox.dll" to "/app/build/libwkhtmltox.dll"`
I tried to fix the error using `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` in csproj file but still doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error MSB3027: Could not copy "C:\pagefile.sys" to "bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428409/error-msb3027-could-not-copy-c-pagefile-sys-to-bin-roslyn-pagefile-sys-ex)

Answer (score 0):

It's not obligatory to add all unless you want to support all platforms.

- so is for Linux
- dll is for Windows
- dylib is for Mac

Next for copying, we have to **Load these Unmanaged Libraries** to assembly
Next **copy these to output path**, in project settings, add

```
    <ItemGroup>
  <None Update="wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\32 bit\libwkhtmltox.dll">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\32 bit\libwkhtmltox.dylib">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\32 bit\libwkhtmltox.so">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  <None Update="wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\64 bit\libwkhtmltox.dll">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\64 bit\libwkhtmltox.dylib">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="wkhtmltox\v0.12.4\64 bit\libwkhtmltox.so">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="wwwroot\**\*">
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```