# Could not copy the file "C:\pagefile.sys" because it was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am consistently encountering this compile time error for a solution in Visual Studio 2017:

> Could not copy the file "C:\pagefile.sys" because it was not found.

This began after fixing a previous warning that `DotNetCompilerPlatform` could not be found in the same project.  This was occurring because the path to `packages` was actually one level higher than where the `.csproj` file indicated. I speculate that happened during a reorganization of project folders prior to my involvement.

Anyway, once fixed I cleaned the project and ran Rebuild All.  The foregoing error cropped up for the first time.

The issue seems similar to these questions:

- [Error MSB3027: Could not copy “C:\pagefile.sys” to “bin\roslyn\pagefile.sys”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428409/error-msb3027-could-not-copy-c-pagefile-sys-to-bin-roslyn-pagefile-sys-ex)
- [Strange Build error after upgrading to Visual studio 2015 wants to copy pagefile.sys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523580/strange-build-error-after-upgrading-to-visual-studio-2015-wants-to-copy-pagefile)

However, I am dealing with a more recent version, `1.0.3`, of `DotNetCompilerPlatform`. So, falling back does not seem like a good option and I am not sure how much of the answers to those questions apply to this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I noticed that multiple versions of `DotNetCompilerPlatform` were installed in the same solution:

[image]

The compile-time error went away after updating both projects to `1.0.7`, though I do not have a lot to say on the how and why.

I also note that there are more up to date versions `DotNetCompilerPlatform`: `1.0.8`, `2.0.0`, and `2.0.1`. For the time being though, I'm content with the smallest update that solves the problem at hand.

**Update** [2019-05-30]**:** Eventually, I did bring all projects up to the latest version of `DotNetCompilerPlatform` and the issue remained resolved so long as all versions in the solution were in sync.